# How to send user details to backend API if client user was authenticated at the API Management service front end?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-api-management

I'm interested in using Azure APIMS to authenticate requests from a client app using Azure AD. However, I am interested in having the backend API know details about the user who was authenticated at the gateway such that I can perform logic based on that user.

Backend API would be ASP.NET Core 3.x web api.

What approaches are available to me?
One thing I can think of off the top of my head is to simply forward the Authentication header along to the backend API, and do some type of lookup there. But I am wondering if there is any way for me to aggregate the user details at the frontend api gateway layer, and pass that information along in a header?

How are backend applications obtaining details about the authenticated user when requests are authenticated at the frontend gateway layer?

I realize that if I was to add authentication at the backend API layer (which would duplicate the authentication/authorization) I may be able to technically accomplish it this way. However, this would violate the SRP principle and perhaps add some necessary overhead to the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD authentication at APIM would mostly imply validating JWT token passed along with request. You can callout to other endpoints if you want to with `send-request` policy to obtain more information (for example, do group expansion), but that would have to be explicitly configured through policies.

After token is validated it's available to you in object model form so you can inspect its properties and use any part of the token in policy expressions, say to send parts of it as headers to your backend API.